# How to compare two arrays without checking each value for simon game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, comparison-operators

This works perfectly but I want to know that here I am checking only the most recent user input value(with their index number) with the randomly generated value and their lengths, but how can I check previous values?

Suppose the user input value is a=[red,blue,green]

and the randomly generated value is b=[red,yellow,green]

Then here I am checking only the a[2] and b[2] which is equal in this case and also their lengths are equal but their elements are not equal.

But in this code, it works perfectly. I want to know how? without a for loop, how can this code check the previous values of that array?

................................***********.............................

```
 var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

 var gamePattern = [];
 var userClickedPattern = [];

 var started = false;
 var level = 0;

 $(document).keypress(function() {
 if (!started) {
 $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
 nextSequence();
 started = true;
 }
 });

 $(".btn").click(function() {

 var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
 userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

 playSound(userChosenColour);
 animatePress(userChosenColour);

 checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length-1);
 });

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {

if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
  if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length){
    setTimeout(function () {
      nextSequence();
    }, 1000);
  }
} else {
  playSound("wrong");
  $("body").addClass("game-over");
  $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");

  setTimeout(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("game-over");
  }, 200);

  startOver();
}
}


function nextSequence() {
userClickedPattern = [];
level++;
$("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

$("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
playSound(randomChosenColour);
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
$("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
setTimeout(function () {
$("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
}, 100);
}

function playSound(name) {
var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
audio.play();
}

function startOver() {
level = 0;
gamePattern = [];
started = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below you can see that when a user clicks a button it calls checkAnswer with `userClickedPattern.length - 1` for level.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

  playSound(userChosenColour);
  animatePress(userChosenColour);

  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length-1);
});
```

When a new sequence starts userClickedPattern is set to `[]`. After the first click it becomes `['red']` and you check if`userClickedPattern[0] // ['red']` is equal to `gamePattern[0] // ['red', 'yellow', 'green']`. And it goes on and on until userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length and user completed with success every checkAnswer (failing it would trigger `startOver` and reset the game)

You are actually checking all the values at runtime when user clicks. The array length check only detects if the user has completed the level.

Comment: But when I pushed 3 values like red,green and yellow,then how can I check index number 0 and 1 because when it entered into nextSequence() it will increment the value of levels.So the index number also incremented.

Comment: Thanks for your ans.I can understand now that there is a if statement without an else.So when I clicked 1st one and it was the right one then it is waiting for my second input(if i am in level 2).If I dont click the second button,it wont go to nextSequence().